# How would I make a different MsgBox appear after the user saw the first one?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, msgbox

I was wondering how to make it so when a user clicks a button, then a MsgBox appears, for example, with the word "cat". Now, since the user saw the word cat, if he would click the button again, for the rest of the time the program is open, it would say "You already know there is a cat here!".

How would I go about this, as is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions that are straight-to-the-point are preferred here, so I have removed your introduction as it is not relevant to your problem. Also, can you please post the code that you have, and show where it isn't working? At the moment your question is quite broad, and will be at risk of closure.

Comment: Please be aware that SO isn't a code writing service. You should come here with code that you've written and that you have a problem with. We can help fix your problems, but we shouldn't write your code for you.

Comment: Question was answered, and thanks for the info! Will make sure to add that in the next question I post! Have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Dim AlreadySawTheCat as Boolean = False

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  If AlreadySawTheCat Then
    MessageBox.Show("You already know there is a cat here!")
  Else
    MessageBox.Show("There is a cat here!")
    AlreadySawTheCat = True
  End If
End Sub
```